# R - TRUE/FALSE needed error when using a for loop and if statement together

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I have an if statement in a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) that works when I put the [Tag:if -statement] or [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) in isolation in the console, but when I run the whole chunk of code I get an error:

> Error in if (CEOsBefore2011$becameceo[z] == CEOsBefore2011$becameceo[z -  : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

And here is the code

```
clean_year <- c(1)
clean_company <-c(1)
clean_total_comp <- c(1)
clean_execid <- c(1)
clean_becameceo <- c(1)

z = 5
for (execid in CEOsBefore2011$becameceo) {
  z = z + 1
  if(CEOsBefore2011$becameceo[z] == CEOsBefore2011$becameceo[z-5]) { 
      clean_year <- c(clean_year, CEOsBefore2011$year[z:z-5])
      clean_company <- c(clean_company, CEOsBefore2011$Company[z:z-5])
      clean_total_comp <- c(clean_total_comp, CEOsBefore2011$TotalComp[z:z-5])
      clean_execid <- c(clean_execid, CEOsBefore2011$execid[z:z-5])
      clean_becameceo <- c(clean_becameceo, CEOsBefore2011$becameceo[z:z-5])
      print(z)
  } else{
  }
}
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is to clean up the data by checking each row. I need to have at least 6 rows in a row of the same becameceo date to be included in the data otherwise remove it. Any thoughts?

A reproducible example to help clear things up is below.
Basically I have this big data frame and I only want to include data where the CEOs have the full 6 years of data so in the example you can see I want to include Alex but exclude john from the data.

So the entire row that John is in should be excluded

I hope this clears things up thank you so much!

```
year <- c(2011,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016)
ceo <- c('john', 'alex', 'alex', 'alex', 'alex', 'alex', 'alex')
comp <- c(45,84,85,86,91,88,91)
combined <- tibble(year = year, ceo = ceo, comp = comp)

clean_year <- c()
clean_ceo <- c()
clean_comp <- c()

z = 5

for (ceo in combined$ceo){
    z = z + 1
    if(combined$ceo[z] == combined$ceo[z-5]){
        clean_year <- c(clean_year, combined$year[z:z-5])
        clean_ceo <- c(clean_ceo, combined$ceo[z:z-5])
        clean_comp <- c(clean_comp, combined$comp[z:z-5])
    } else{
    }
}
```

Comment: I would guess that there are missings in `CEOsBefore2011$becameceo`, e.g. the line of code `if (NA == 5) print("Hello") else print("World")` results in `Error in if (NA == 5) print("Hello") else print("World") : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` .

Comment: please provide a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and provide your data using dput(). I am unsure what you are trying to do with the for loop as you are looping over execid while not using it later one. Also, I feel like this could easier be rewriten using `dplyr`.

Comment: The error arises because in `combined$ceo[z]` you are trying to get elements which are not present in your vector. R will tell you that if you change  the if-condition to `combined$ceo[[z]] == combined$ceo[[z-5]]`, i.e. if you use double brackets. In that case R gives you the error `Error in combined$ceo[[z]] : subscript out of bounds`.

Comment: Thank you very much Stefan! How would I go about fixing this error? or is there another method to get the data that I want instead of the current code I am using.

Comment: As @Annet suggested, it is easier to filter the data without using a for loop. For example you can count the number of rows for each CEO and filter only the CEOs with six rows: `ceos <- combined %>% group_by(ceo) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% filter(n == 6) %>% pull(ceo)`. Then you filter the original data: `cleaned_combined <- combined %>% filter(ceo %in% ceos)`

Comment: Thank you guys so much I have literally only used it for a few days how do you mark the question as solved I can't find it

Comment: @davide you do not even have to summarise, `group_by(ceo) %>% filter(n() == 6)` will also work

Comment: Keep however in mind that filtering only tests for six observations, i.e. not necessarily observations in a row. But if your data consists of no more than 6 years it will work.